# getting "App deployment failed. Please try again. " while running Windows phone 8 emulator

Tags: windows-phone-8, emulation, windows-phone-8-emulator

I am developing Windows phone 8 app. When I try to run the emulator of WXGA or 720p I am constantly getting this error. Searching regarding this error leads to the conculsion that I should not run more and more app parallely. So I ran only VS2012 then also getting the error. I am having enough 4GB of RAM then also having problem. My friend's PC has 2 GB of RAM then also it works flawlessly in it. Anyone know what's the issue & best practice to run the emulator smoothly?

PS : I don't have REAL Windows Phone device :(

Comment: is it runs fine on real device ?

Comment: I don't own WP8 device :(

Answer (score 2):

Just try rebooting your Windows 8 Phone. I just had the same issue, and rebooting worked for me while deploying on device.

Answer (score 1):

Please ensure you have following to get rid of the error,

- Minimum Hardware/software requirements (https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/oem?contentName=docs%2FGetting_Started%2FPreparing_for_Windows_Phone_development)
- Valid developer license/account to develop windows phone applications
- Enough free RAM (>2GB RAM should be free)
- Not more than one instance of VS is trying to use same emulator.

If everything is holds good then try following,

1. Restart emulator & check if it fixed the issue, if not go to next step.
2. Go to Hyper-V manager and delete all the virtual switches related to WP. If it doesn't fix issue go to next step.
3. Go to Hyper-V manager and delete all the windows phone virtual machines. repair WP SDK from control panel.

More info about troubleshooting errors like this can be found at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/b06cc9f2-aa5e-4cb3-9df1-0c273e1dfd68/wp8-emulator-xde-troubleshooting-tips?forum=wptools :)

In worst case, you will have to uninstall & install WP SDK.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The emulator may not work when its dedicated requirements are not perfectly matched. [Emulator Requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626524%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
You can always try deploying an app by selecting 'Device' in the emulator which will actually deploy the app on your phone and you can test it out.

note: Make sure you're using the right version of app which is to be deployed in its righteous OS version.
Also try to restart your emulator/device

Comment: I don't have Lumia device :'(

Comment: Actually my requirement is to take screenshot of the app in different resolutions to add while uploading on Store.

Answer (score 0):

Well. This might be happens because of some inner problems of Emulator. Because even me too faced this same problem some days ago. So, let me tel you what I have did and how I got rid of that problem. So, try as per my instruction and if this works. Just Mark it as an answer. else, comment what you have got after.

1. Check all Emulator `VGA and VXGA and 720p`
2. After you got that error, just tap Ok or Cancel in the dialog box and go to

Open Emulator -> Strat Screen will be shown -> goto All Apps -> Check your app name (It will exist and open your app and take screenshots)

I am sure this will be works for you.

Comment: Where is "Emulator -> All Apps"?

Comment: All Apps (Swiping right side from Start Screen) this is where you can find your app

Comment: But I am not getting emulator open, when I get error emulator is closed. I am not facing issues in deploying app but opening the emulator.

Comment: Are you using laptop or desktop ?

Answer (score 0):

Only restart the device or the emulator and the deployment will success